# React Show / hide toggle with trigger outside of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a toggle show / hide react element with the trigger outside of the component ... or at least, that's what I think I'm trying to create

I'm fairly new to React and this seems like the best way to approach what I am after with React but if not please let me know!

So I have my trigger button which is placed before some content and when pressed I want to toggle the buttons content which is a form (which will be the same form for each area which is why I would like to make it a component).

```
<span>Toggle show/hide button</span>
<p>Irrelevant content</p>
<ToggleContent />

<span>Toggle show/hide button</span>
<p>Irrelevant content</p>
<ToggleContent />

<span>Toggle show/hide button</span>
<p>Irrelevant content</p>
<ToggleContent />
```

So my question is, is this the right way to structure what I am trying to do with React and how would I start putting this together? I've been trying to find a similar solution to my problem but couldn't so if anyone knows of one that already exists if you could point me in the right direction I'd be hugely grateful!

Thank you for you time reading this!

Comment: Can you provide more on your usecase ? Like what does `ToggleContent` contains ?

Comment: @yuantonito Ok - ToggleContent is a huge form and I mean HUGE - this is why I'd like it to not render until it's needed, there could be 20-30 of these content areas and most of the time users will not want to see the ToggleContent and if they do likely only one. The tigger is set in a table with top level information and is a 'edit this content' sort of thing, the form will then be displayed under the table row .. this is why the tigger is separate from the component, hope that helps!

Comment: Ok I'm going to write an answer but I need more information on your code. Can you show me how to handle your state in your form ? Do you use redux or directly state in components ?

Comment: This is pretty early on in development - the form is just a static hard coded form at the moment, there's nothing to plumb it in to yet so that is something that will be done later, not sure if that helps or is what you're after?

Comment: I believe you should write some code first before I can help you. Otherwise it will be difficult for you to learn the philosophy of React

Comment: So I'm currently building the front end structure of what will become a React App - I will not be building the app itself, I need to know how to structure React components but I don't (believe) I need to know how to plumb in the form and build all of those components - that's definitely not how we're structured our team, but it would be very helpful if I could structure the app correctly ie - create a toggle element, hope that makes sense but anyway thank you very much for your time looking in to this